# Declaring object in drools excel descision table

Tags: java, drools

I'm trying to use a Drools decision table.
The problem I'm facing is that drools does not assign a variable for me with the current object.

I get this error from drools:

> Drools error: Rule Compilation error patient cannot be resolved

My excel file looks like this:

[image]

And part of my lab code looks like this:

```
DecisionTableConfiguration dtconf = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newDecisionTableConfiguration();
        dtconf.setInputType(DecisionTableInputType.XLS);
        dtconf.setWorksheetName("Sheet1"); 

        KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
        Resource r = ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("rules.xls");
        kbuilder.add(r, ResourceType.DTABLE, dtconf);

        SpreadsheetCompiler compiler = new SpreadsheetCompiler();
        String drl = compiler.compile(r.getInputStream(), InputType.XLS);

        System.out.println(drl);

        if(kbuilder.hasErrors()) {
            for(KnowledgeBuilderError err : kbuilder.getErrors()) {
                System.out.println("Drools error: " + err.getMessage());
            }
            model.addAttribute("droolErrors", kbuilder.getErrors());
            return "index";
        }

        KnowledgeBase knowledgeBase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
        knowledgeBase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages()); 
        StatefulKnowledgeSession dsess = knowledgeBase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();

        for(Patient p : patients) {
            dsess.insert(p);
        }

        model.addAttribute("factCount", dsess.getFactCount());

        KnowledgeRuntimeLogger logger = KnowledgeRuntimeLoggerFactory.newFileLogger(dsess, "test"); 

        int res = dsess.fireAllRules();
        System.out.println(res);
        dsess.dispose();


        logger.close();
```

The generated drl looks like this:

```
package com.sorkmos.drools.domain;
//generated from Decision Table
import com.sorkmos.drools.domain.*;
// rule values at C11, header at C6
rule "Risks rules_11"
    when
        Patient(age == 75)
    then
        patient.setAge(22);
end


Drools error: Rule Compilation error patient cannot be resolved
```

It's quite obvious I need to set the "patient" variable. But I can't figure out how. 
A correct drl version would be like this:

```
package com.sorkmos.drools.domain;
//generated from Decision Table
import com.sorkmos.drools.domain.*;
// rule values at C11, header at C6
rule "Risks rules_11"
    when
        Patient(age == 75);
        patient: Patient();
    then
        patient.setAge(22);
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the Patient pattern that goes from Cell C to G doesn't define any variable. If you are sure you want to have 2 separate Patient patterns then you have to bind a variable there. Of course, if you bind 'patient', then make sure that columns C to G and H are exclusive. Otherwise you will end up with duplicated variable definition. 
According to the scarce information I have, I guess you don't want to have to different Patient patterns. If that is the case, just merge cell H8 with [C-G]8 and make sure the value is patient:Patient.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Yes, I merged C-H and set the variable to patient: Patient. Thanks!